# What is an adjective for something that can anticipate any input?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

For example:

> "Form A" is able to anticipate any kind of input. Like, can take in
>   Japanese characters, block illegal characters, and any other sort of
>   characters. Hence, "Form A" is _____ble.

Basically, i am trying to replicate something like:

- "Superman is able to withstand a super nova.  Hence, he is invincible."
- "David saved a kitten.  Hence, he is admirable."
- "Rob was a able to solve the problem.  Hence, the problem is solvable."

If there is not really any word, any other suggestions?

Comment: Form A is omniscient.

Comment: *Flexible* or *versatile*

Answer (score 1):

`Form A` is able to anticipate any kind of input, hence it is universal.

Answer (score 1):

Usually one says that the method/process is *robust*.

Comment: Note that this is computer science jargon, and so it means something slightly different to how 'robust' is used in general English. It will probably get the point across, though, for all but a close reader.

Comment: Not just computer scientists, many [engineers](http://www.amazon.com/Robust-Engineering-Quality-Reducing-Market/dp/0071347828) and [statisticians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_statistics) will probably get it.

Comment: Please include a definition and a link to that definition, or you'll likely be deleted for not providing enough information.

Comment: Why does one usually say that?

Comment: The wikipedia page for 'robust' explicitly references handling unusual and expected inputs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_(computer_science)